# How to remove a part of the string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am wondering How i can remove a part if my string .

For example my string will be :

```
 string test = "/blabla/test/ok";
```

How can I say that I want to remove /blabla/ ?

And my string will be /test/ok.

Comment: Google ".net string" or something similar

Comment: Is is always going to be 6 digit string?? the one you need to remove. in above case **blabla**

Comment: Removing `/blabla/` does not result in `/test/ok`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about stripping the first 8 characters?

```
test = test.Substring(7);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
test = test.Replace("/blabla/", string.Empty);
```

Or

```
test = test.Substring("/blabla/".Length - 1);
```

You really should take a look at the documentation of the [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) class and all the different methods and properties it holds.

Answer (score 3):

```
test = test.Replace("/blabla", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply **[.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)** it:

```
test.Replace("/blabla/",""); //Yields /test/ok
```

Answer (score 0):

If you what to do it in more general case you'll need regular expressions here:

```
Regex.Replace(@"/blabla/test/ok", @"^//(.*?)//(.*?)//(.*?)$", @"/$2/$3")
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you're going to be snipping out the same bit of text every single time or whether the text you're removing can differ.

If you know it's a particular block of text which will only appear once in the string then use Curt's answer (`test = test.replace("/blabla", "");`).

If it's anything else then, personally, I'd use a variant of Arcturus's answer to snip out the unwanted segment of the string (`test = test.Substring(7);`).

That's my two cents anyway.